# How to edit an Xml file's element values

Tags: c#, xml, settings, edit, updating

I have this Xml file, and I want to edit any of the elements like `homepage` or `search_provider`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Preferences>
      <personal>
        <homepage>http://duckduckgo.com</homepage>
        <search_provider>DuckDuckGo</search_provider>
        <search_provider_url>http://duckduckgo.com/?q=</search_provider_url>
      </personal>
    </Preferences>
```

The following is the C# code I'm using to attempt to change the homepage element. Let's say I run `saveSetting("homepage", "http://google.com");`

```
            public static void saveSetting(String settingName, String newvalue)
            {
               XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

               xml.Load(userSettingsFile);

               foreach (XmlElement element in xml.SelectNodes("Preferences"))
               {
                   foreach (XmlElement oldsettingname in element)
                   {
                       element.SelectSingleNode(settingName);

                       XmlNode settingtosave = xml.CreateElement(settingName);

                       settingtosave.InnerText = newvalue;

                       element.ReplaceChild(settingtosave, oldsettingname);

                       xml.Save(userSettingsFile);
                   }
               }
            }
```

Now, while this works to an extent and does change the specified value, it also deletes the entire `personal` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Preferences>
  <homepage>http://google.com</homepage>
</Preferences>
```

Hopefully someone can help me out! I've been searching for the last two days for a solution and this is the closest I've come to getting the code to work the way I need it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [`LINQ to XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387087.aspx) like this:

```
public static void saveSetting(String settingName, String newvalue)
{
    var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("path");

    var element = xmlDocument.Descendants(settingName).FirstOrDefault();

    if (element != null) element.Value = newvalue;

    xmlDocument.Save("path");
}
```

See this documentation for more details: [Modifying Elements, Attributes, and Nodes in an XML Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387052.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. I really do appreciate the help! It won't let me up vote your answer though.

Comment: @jothousand your welcome.You can accept this as answer if it's solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

keep your current code and just modify a few lines:

```
public static void saveSetting(String settingName, String newvalue)
{
   XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

   xml.Load(userSettingsFile);

   foreach (XmlElement element in xml.SelectNodes("Preferences"))
   {
     if(element.Name.Equals(settingName))
     {
        element.InnerText = newvalue;
        break;
     }
   }

   xml.Save(userSettingsFile);
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, it did the same thing as the code I already have. Thank you for your help though, @Selman22's answer worked for me!